# /etc/manpath.config missing when I reinstall manpage

Tags: 16.04, apt, manpage, purge

```
$apt install man
apt-get install manpages-zh
```

then

```
    apt-get purge manpages-zh

$apt purge manpage
```

then

```
$apt install man
$apt-get install manpages-zh
```

it shows

```
/usr/bin/mandb: can't open the manpath configuration file /etc/manpath.config
```

I find the manpath.config is missing
And whenever I reinstall how many times
I got the same error!!!
just like below

```
$man ls
man: can't open the manpath configuration file /etc/manpath.config
```

how can I fix it and how can I uninstall man?
As when I use

```
$apt purge man
```

it shows

```
select man-db not man?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/manpath.config 
man-db: /etc/manpath.config
```

The `/etc/manpath.config` file is part of the `man-db` package.

Comment: thanks for your help! I can't find  the -S option meaning? I use $man dpkg.